# Solutions of the functional equation $f\big(x+g(y)\big)=f(x)+f\big(g(y)\big)$

Tags: functional-equations

I know the solutions of the well-known Cauchy functional equation
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\text.$$
But what does it change if I have the following form
$$f\big(x+g(y)\big)=f(x)+f\big(g(y)\big)\text?$$
What can I say about $g$?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possibilities.  For example, you might have $g(y) = 1$ for all $y$, in which case $f(x+1) = f(x) + f(1)$ just says that $f(x) = f(1) x + p(x)$ where $p(x)$ is periodic with period $1$ and $p(1) = p(0) = 0$.  On the other hand, if $g$ is surjective, the equation reduces to Cauchy's.

EDIT: For any possible nonzero value $v$ of $g$, we have 
$$f(x + v) = f(x) + f(v)$$
and then $$f(x) = p(x) + \dfrac{f(v)}{v} x$$ 
where 
$p(x) = f(x) - \dfrac{f(v)}{v} x$ is periodic with period $v$.
Nonlinear cases with two or more incommensurate $v$'s are going to be quite
exotic (nonmeasurable, I would expect, just like nonlinear solutions to the Cauchy equation).

Comment: thank you.
is it possible to say that the solutions are of the form:

$f(x)=f(g(y))x+p(x)$ with $p(x+kg(y))=p(x)$ for an integer k?
or do i loose some solutions?

Comment: oh sorry i meant for p the condition $p(x+g(y))=p(x)+p(g(y))$